# How to redraw/refresh BarChart in Android/Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, refresh, bar-chart, redraw

in my app I'm using BarChart Library to draw plots. I am creating BarModels dynamically during app's action.

**Here is the code responsible for creating Chart**:

```
void tworzWykres(int ilosc){

        List<float> listImport = getHistoricalRates (wykresWybor,ilosc);

        if (listImport.Count == 0) {
            Toast.MakeText (this, "Brak notowań dla tej waluty!", ToastLength.Short).Show ();
        }
         else if (ilosc > listImport.Count) {
            Toast.MakeText (this, "Zmniejsz ilość notowań", ToastLength.Short).Show ();
        } else {

            BarModel[] data = new BarModel[listImport.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < listImport.Count; i++) {
                data [i] = new BarModel() { Value = listImport [i], Legend = daty[i]};
            }
            chart = FindViewById<BarChartView> (Resource.Id.barChart);
            chart.ItemsSource = data;
            chart.Invalidate ();
        }
```

I invoke that method in Click event for my Button. 
After clicking the button, only grid and axis are shown - **bars are hidden**,
but when I click on some edittext and keyboard overlaps on the chart area, bars appear.
I am new in Android programming and I can't figure it out, how to solve this. I want bars to appear immediately after clicking the button.
I hope you know how to solve that :)

Answer (score 0):

Is there DataBind, or Rebind methods or something similar? Try to call them right after setting the new item source.

Answer (score 0):

This might be late to respond, but even i had got the same issues in Graph redraw/refresh with different value. Recreating the batChartView when i had the issue worked for me.

```
BarChartView barChart;
void fnInitializeBarChart()
        {
            if ( barChart != null )
            {
                barChart.BarClick -= fnBarModelClicked; 
                lyBarChart.RemoveView (barChart);
                barChart.Dispose ();
                barChart = null; 
            } 
            barChart = barChart ?? new BarChartView (this);
            barChart.BarOffset = 25f;
            barChart.BarWidth = 80f;
            barChart.MinimumValue = 0f;
            barChart.BarClick += fnBarModelClicked;  
            lyBarChart.AddView(barChart,new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the chart color to black and then back to the original color. Refreshes new data on chart. Works fine.

```
chart.BarColor = Android.Graphics.Color.Black;

chart.BarColor = Android.Graphics.Color.Blue;
```